Is delegatecall to another contract really same as calling the function as if it were the part of calling contract?
When a contract makes a delegatecall, the code at the target address is executed in the context of the calling contract. This means that the storage, state variables, and functions of the calling contract are accessible to the code being executed, which means as if the function of target contract is a part of calling contract.
That means if a function in contract makes delegatecall to a function in the same contract it should behave the same way as any other normal call to that function would.
Then in the following contract :-
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
    pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

    import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
    import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

    contract BuggyNFTVault is ERC721 {
        using Counters for Counters.Counter;
        Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

        uint256 public constant DEPOSIT = 1 ether;

        /// @notice Stores the amount of ETH deposited by each user.
        mapping(address => uint256) public deposits;

         constructor() ERC721("CtfNFT", "CNFT") {
    }

        /**
         * @notice Deposits ETH and mints an NFT in return.
         */
        function deposit() external payable {
            require(msg.value == DEPOSIT, "Incorrect ETH amount");

            _tokenIds.increment();
            uint256 newTokenId = _tokenIds.current();

            deposits[msg.sender] += msg.value;

            _mint(msg.sender, newTokenId);
        }

            function batch() external payable {
            for (uint256 i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
               (bool success,)= address(this).delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("deposit()"));
                 require(success, "reverted");
            }
        }
    }


when an eoa calls batch function with 1ether the eoa is able to receive 5nfts (similar to critical vulnerability in the sushi batch auction contract),
but when
(bool success,)= address(this).delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("deposit()"));
                  

is replaced with
(bool success,)= address(this).call(abi.encodeWithSignature("deposit()"));

and similarly eoa calls the batch function with 1ether the transaction fails.
Why is it so when both should behave the same way if we go by the definition of delegatecall.

Because, when you use delegatecall, the transaction context remains unchanged. Means msg.sender and msg.value will remain same as the initial tx.
But using call, it becomes a new internal transaction. Means the contract becomes msg.sender and the msg.value is also 0.
To understand this, change this line
(bool success,)= address(this).call(abi.encodeWithSignature("deposit()"));

To this
(bool success,)= address(this).call{value: 1e18}(abi.encodeWithSignature("deposit()"));

And then when you will call the batch function, the contract address will receive those 5 tokens. NOT THE EOA

I was on it since morning, although while typing the question and posting it I was able to get some clue of what is going wrong but you made it more clear now !
Thank you so much !

Great, could you mark this as the answer if it answers the question?
